# What type of cable is a cat 7 : UTP or STP ?

Tags: layer1, cable

I'm a ICT engineering student studying networking. I was wondering if someone could tell me what type of a cable Cat7 is ?

Comment: ANSI never defined "cat 7", so the question is nonsense. Do you mean ISO Class F?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Cat 7 is neither UTP or STP.  It is typically either F/FTP or S/FTP.

Comment: FTP is `foil-shielded twisted pair`, where each pair is shielded separately from the other pairs to lower cross-talk.  Adding to save someone else the google time...

Comment: @cpt_fink, actually FTP generally uses foil on the cable, not the pairs.  By the "newer" ISO/IEC spec, which hasn't caught on in some places, this would more accurately be F/UTP.  F/FTP specificies a foil shield on both the cable and on each pair.  S/FTP would be a braided shield on the cable and foil on each pair.